# Syntax Error when using <> to wrap multiple <div>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-error

I'm trying to wrap multiple  components in a return, and when using the <></> to wrap it(I lack a better term), it keeps throwing a syntax error.

```
export default function Board() {
  const [squares, setSquare] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
  const [val, setVal] = useState(true);

  function handleClick(i) {
    const nextSquare = squares.slice();
    if (val) nextSquare[i] = "X";
    else nextSquare[i] = "O";
    setSquare(nextSquare);
    setVal(!val);
  }

  return (
    <>                                     //This is the line that throws the syntax error
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[0]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(0)} />
        <Square value={squares[1]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(1)} />
        <Square value={squares[2]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(2)} />
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[3]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(3)} />
        <Square value={squares[4]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(4)} />
        <Square value={squares[5]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(5)} />
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[6]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(6)} />
        <Square value={squares[7]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(7)} />
        <Square value={squares[8]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(8)} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I'm using VSCode and have used this before. The code seems to work on CodeSandbox perfectly fine.

I have tried using this <> </> syntax in a far simpler code and it seems to work, but not in this one.

Edit: As asked, the error is

> Syntax error: D:/React Project/tic-tac/src/App.js: Unexpected token (25:5)

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: @SrushtiShah I have edited the question to answer that. Thanks.

Comment: Are you really facing Unexpected token error ? As I am not seeing any syntax error in the above code when the comment is removed, Can you please check once again

Comment: "I lack a better term" they're called JSX fragments. Some versions of babel do not support the shorthand form (`<></>`), try using `<React.Fragment>{...}</React.Fragment>` instead. You can also try renaming your JSX files from *.js to *.jsx, this may help with your intellisense.

Comment: @Undo Thank you for the answer. When I use `<React.Fragment>` I get multiple of the same error throughout the code. 

`Line 6:   'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope`

Renaming the JSX files as you recommended gives me this.
`./src/App.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\React Project\tic-tac\src\App.js'`

Sorry if I'm too ignorant. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @HetalN Yes. As mentioned, I have tried on a different code segment which was far simpler, and it worked and the same code works online. For some reason this one does not.

Comment: You have to import React in every JSX file that uses React add `import React from "react";` at the top of your jsx files

Answer (score 0):

I would ask you to check your system environment i.e., required softwares and its versions installed in your PC and verify with the CodeSandbox dependancy.

Also, There may be chances of missing required versions issue of the environment setup in your system as well, You may check that as well.

Also, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unexpected_token),

> The JavaScript exceptions "unexpected token" occurs when a specific
> language construct was expected, but something else was provided.